# What's the most common name/brand for my EM73_SIS_ALL android tablet?

Tags: stock-android

Some time ago (around 2 years) I was offered an Android tablet from a friend that went to China. It's an intersting equipment, but  it moves slow and the power management is very innefective.

I was thinking on updating it with a new rom, just to see if I could improve it's usability a bit. Unfortunaly I have no idea what model this is.

The model reported in the definitions menu tells that is a EM73_SIS_ALL. It comes with android 2.3.3

I googled for this model but I get no relevant information.
There is no visible information on the exterior case except for some chinese characters.
I think this is probably a "white-label" model and it's sold with other brands/names in Europe.

Anyone knows what model this is and how it's known in the Android world?

[image: Front]
[image]